# What do you call the portion of a tail-dragger takeoff when the tail is in the air?

Tags: takeoff, terminology, tail-dragger

During a take-off roll out down the runway, in a tail-dragger airplane, what is the period of time called where the plane is level, with the main gear still on the runway, but the tail has come up off the ground and before you pull back on the stick to begin climb-out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no term (that I am aware of) referring to only the portion of the takeoff while the tail is off the ground.

In general, the attitude where just the two main wheels are touching the ground is called "two-point." Likewise, with the tail wheel also on the ground, it is called "three-point."

Specifically, a two-point landing is sometimes called a "wheel landing".

[Source](http://www.richstowell.com/services/tailwheel-training/)

Comment: When I first wrote the question, I was thinking it was maybe 'on the step', as in a water-borne take-off. After actually doing some research, I've come to the conclusion that it isn't named, mostly because a tail-dragger pilot is more concerned with maintaining the straightline of the rollout (vice ground looping) than naming a portion of the take off.

Comment: Those were my thoughts exactly.

Comment: fooot could you maybe add a line to your answer stating that there really isn't a 'name' per se? I'll accept it then.